Remote-Controlled Ceiling Light OK?
In my ceiling is a recessed light box that is live via a breaker.  The old light had a pull chain to turn it off.  My new ceiling light has a remote control for on/off.  Will this be safe?

As long as the remote works/you can find it before you step on lego block, then yes.

There are two possible concerns here. I'm going to assume US code.
First - if there is no other switchable light in the room, and it's a habitable room, this isn't allowed. Code ref:

210.70(A)(1) Habitable Rooms. At least one lighting outlet controlled by a listed wall-mounted control device shall be installed in every habitable room, kitchen, and bathroom. The wall-mounted control device shall be located near an entrance to the room on a wall.

Second - if it's not listed, well, that's a different problem. This is most likely to happen when you buy stuff on eBay/Amazon/Aliexpress.
To answer your direct question:
If it's a listed fixture it will be safe, assuming proper installation.
If it's the last fixture in the room, it needs to have the remote mounted by a door, and be listed. Then it will be safe.

"A listed wall-mounted control device" is actually updated language that permits a listed wall-mounted remote control to meet the requirement. Pretty sure it used to say "switch" there, without reviewing code changes. You can have an additional remote control that's not wall-mounted, if you like; the wall-mounted one satisfies code.

Yes, this was a 2020 code revision. Note that it is still required to be mounted; not sure if one of the standard cheapo IR remotes these things often have would count if stuck to the wall with double stick tape. It might depend on the AHJ. The old revision read:  At least one wall switch–controlled lighting outlet shall be installed in every habitable room, kitchen, and bathroom.
